# View not updating in angular 4

Tags: angular

Im setting an array value in one component inside subscribe and doing get of the values of array in another component. Once I get the values, I'm setting a flag in the component where I did get of array values. But the view doesn't update the flag. Can anyone please help?

```
Firstcomponent.component.ts


storedataservice:[] = IUser[] ;
ngOnInit() { 
    this.changeinsomeservice.susbscribe(getUsers()) ;
} 

getUsers() {
this.someService.someObservable.subscribe(
    (users: IUser[]) => {
        this.storedataservice.setUsers(users);
    });
} 



Secondcomponent. Component.ts


loading :boolean = true ;
users :[]=[] ;

ngOnInit() 
{
   this.users = this.storedataservice.getUsers();
   If (this.users.length>0) {
       this.loading = false ;
    } 
}
```

View template of second component which has the issue. Where in loading is not getting set to false. So even though backend is done getting data it's showing loading symbol.

```
<div *ngIf=loading >
      Show loading Image
<div>

<div *ngIf=!loading >
      Show tabular data of users 
<div>
```

Comment: Hello! Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask in order to get to know how to ask a good question from which we can start investigating your issue.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by get the values in another component but from what you are describing, you might want to look at @Input decorator and ngOnChanges lifecycle hook, if you are not already doing so.

Comment: @krishna Could you please help now. Have added snippet.

Answer (score 0):

```
getUsers(){
  return this.someService.someObservable.subscribe(
    (users: IUser[]) => {
        this.storedataservice.setUsers(users);
    });
}

...

Second Component

import {ApplicationRef} from '@angular/core';

constructor(private appRef: ApplicationRef, ...){...}

...

ngOnit(){
  this.users = [];
  this.service.getUser().subscribe(users => {
    this.users = users;
    if(this.users.length > 0){ this.loading = false }
    this.appRef.tick();
  });
}
```

EDIT: Included manual change detection.

Comment: Edited. Can you please try now.